# Jar file does not work with database (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created an application using hibernate... It works fine with database when I run it through Netbeans. But when I build application (using Clean and Build tool) it does not work with database.

Error:

```
WARNING: SQL Error: 40000, SQLState: 08001
May 21, 2010 4:25:11 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port
1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"    
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: **Cannot open connection**
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert( SQLStateConverter.java:74)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.conver t(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.conver t(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnectio n(ConnectionManager.java:426)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection (ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQuerySta tement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement( Loader.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:67 3)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNo nLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:222 0)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(L oader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoa der.java:378)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(Que ryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performLis t(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.ja va:1121)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:7 9)
at ajmalispatientdatamanager.StartPage.searchMethod(S tartPage.java:852)
at ajmalispatientdatamanager.StartPage.SearchBtnActio nPerformed(StartPage.java:599)
at ajmalispatientdatamanager.StartPage.access$900(Sta rtPage.java:33)
at ajmalispatientdatamanager.StartPage$8.actionPerfor med(StartPage.java:382)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unk nown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed (Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed (Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseRe leased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent( Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(U nknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unkno wn Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilter s(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(U nknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarch y(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException :   
Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: 
connect.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.g etSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLExce ption(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionPr   
ovider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvid er.java:110)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnectio n(ConnectionManager.java:423)
 ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : 
Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused:   
connect.
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknow n Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent _(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unkno wn Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(U nknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init> (Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactor yImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown 
Source)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknow n Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(U nknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 53 more
```

Please Help Me.
Please Help Me.

Comment: And when it was working, was it connecting to localhost on port 1527?

Comment: Do *not* post the same question twice because you didn't get an answer; doing so may result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 0):

This has no relationship to the jar - rather, it's a database connection privileges issue.

1) the address or account information in your hibernate configuration, which is packaged with the jar- is incorrect or incomplete compared to that used by your working netbeans code.... Are you using the same configration file in your jar as netbeans?

Or

2). You are running the jar from a machine which is not authorized to connect to the database - for example, maybe you are connecting as root from a non root authorized ip address.... Are you running the jar on the same machine which you use netbeans on?